# Programmatically lock into portrait mode for certain operations

Tags: android

Is there a way to programmatically lock an app in portrait mode for certain operations, and then resume (and have the app rotate to landscape if the user is holding the device that way) after the operation is complete?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Try this:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
//Do your operation
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

Comment: I had to use `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT` instead of `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR`.

Comment: If the user is holding a tablet in REVERSE_PORTRAIT, this will change the orientation to portrait and then again to the sensor. So I I could get the orientation value using `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` but it returns 1 for both portrait as well as reverse_portrait.... How can I get the correct orientation? Thanks

Comment: I am now using `orientation = getRequestedOrientation();` which returns the correct orientation value... it might help someone :)

Comment: You "unset" an app's orientation preference with  `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED`. `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR` will override user configuration to prefer the hardware orientation.

Answer (score 4):

I'm reading into your question a bit, but if the problem you are facing is that the reload of the activity causes problems, you can add in the manifest a line to handle the orientation changes yourself.  You'll probably need to do this anyway if you want to do something special for the orientation changes, but perhaps just adding the lines will take care of your problems for you:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"  
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this in OnCreate Method of Activity if you want to set Screen only in Portrait

```
 setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

If you want only LANDSCAPE so use this line

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

This one Line is Enough

Like this below

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    }
```