# How do I make it only landscape for tablets and only portrait for phones?

Tags: android, android-layout

how can it so that when a tablet is running the application, it is forced to run it in landscape and when a phone is running the application, it is forced to run it in portrait? I've managed to force it to run in lets say portrait, but then it run portrait for tablets too... Portrait mode in tablets is ugly :( Thanks

Comment: This solution worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60381441/7826494

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:
First try to determine the type of device using screen dimensions. You could refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions). 
On the second step you can change the screen orientation using `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`. There is another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654675/programmatically-lock-into-portrait-mode-for-certain-operations).

Answer (score 2):

Just set nosensor parameter for activity in manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" 
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor">
```

By the way, some tablets may be detected as phones, for example Nexus 7.