# Force Landscape Orientation on Actionbar Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I would like to click on a tab on my action bar and force a change to landscape orientation, and resume portrait orientation when I click back on other tabs.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

This is taken from the following question: [Programmatically lock into portrait mode for certain operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654675/programmatically-lock-into-portrait-mode-for-certain-operations)