# How to set portrait view for android application

Tags: android, android-view

In my application I have 10 activities. I want to set portrait view for all pages. How to do it pro-grammatically.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654675/programmatically-lock-into-portrait-mode-for-certain-operations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it  pro-grammatically in every activity.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the AndroidManifest.xml for doing this. Code you need:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```