# How do I lock the sceen from rotating in a steroids.js - AppGyver mobile app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, steroids

Well the title is self explanatory.There are many guides for phonegap - cordova but none for a steroids project.
Does anyone have any idea on how to accomplish orientation lock in an android app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppGyver employee here – I just wrote a quick [device orientation guide](http://guides.appgyver.com/steroids/guides/phonegap_on_steroids/device-orientation/) about the issue. Hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

so locking the orieb=ntation is independed of plugin you are using. Just lock the orientation in adroid app in manifest/Mainclass.

[Lock screen orientation (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675750/lock-screen-orientation-android)

[Programmatically lock into portrait mode for certain operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654675/programmatically-lock-into-portrait-mode-for-certain-operations)