# How to develop Android application for tablet in landscape mode and for phone in portrait mode

Tags: java, android, tablet, android-3.0-honeycomb

How to develop Android application for tablet in landscape mode and in portrait mode for Phones?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0):

You can provide alternate layouts. Create folder `/res/layout-land`  and put your layout xml file in it.

Answer (score 0):

Now to make your App screen to work in both orientations as expected, please follow the below steps:

1. As shown in the below screenshot, under “res” folder, create a new folder with the name “layout-land”, -land appended for landscape orientation.
2. For landscape orientation, create layout xml under “layout-land” folder with the same name as of the layout xml under “layout” folder. Note that name of the xml file in layout and layout-land folder should be same.

[Screen orientation–Portrait / Landscape](http://mdaslam.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/android-programming-screen-orientationportrait-landscape/)

and even try to mention this

```
&lt;supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
                  android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/&rt;
```

[image: In this manner image provider]

Answer (score 0):

You should have to check device type programmatically [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet). If the device is mobile then lock app orientation to portrait otherwise lock orientation to landscape mode.[(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654675/programmatically-lock-into-portrait-mode-for-certain-operations) And you need two layout  folders - layout and layout-land.

Answer (score -1):

Disable the device's orientation sensor by setting the attribute in the activity tag in the manifest file like this:

```
android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
```

When you run your app, by default portrait orientation is set for phones and landscape for tablets(and hence it'll select the xml file from `layout-xlarge-land`). And since you've set an orientation lock, it remains in this orientation.