# screen orientation landscape view doesn't working

Tags: android, landscape, android-gallery

In these project screen orientation landscape view wasn't working at all.

In android `manifest` I did `android:screen orientation=lanscape` or doesn't use screen orientation in that.You can check it in manifest.But unfortunately I doesn't get a output.

**Manifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gems.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" 
    android:installLocation="auto"
    >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.sit.gems.app.GemsApplication"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.sit.gems.activity.SplashActivity"

            android:label="@string/app_name"  >
                 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.sit.gems.activity.HomeActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.sit.gems.activity.YoutubePlayActivity"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I doesn't get a landscape view.
Anybody know how to solve these.Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "landscape view"? Do you mean screen orientation? What you see on screen when you ratate your device? Have you debugged your code? Do you have different xml layout for portrait and landscape

Comment: you use different layouts?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno did you know where exactly the problem occurs?

Comment: No sorry i mean: one layout for landscape and another for portrait or the same?

Comment: hopse so you had not put oriantion code in activity

Comment: And check on notification bar you had on screen roatation option\

Comment: @PankajAndroid what is the usage to put a orientation code in activity.I think I need to put a code in manifest only?

Comment: If you are using emulator,then some of the emulator targets like Android 4.4 and 2.3 have a bug.
Try to change your emulator to target version 4.2 or 4.3 and try to change the orientation.

Comment: no in activity also u can define oriantation check it and you screen rotation option is on or off?

Comment: @Tinker ok.I am gonna try it now.

Comment: @Stephen u can check activity oriantiaon via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654675/programmatically-lock-into-portrait-mode-for-certain-operations

Comment: @PankajAndroid k.will check that post and tell u.

Comment: Change you emulator target to 4.2 or 4.3 version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using emulator,then some of the emulator with targets version Android 4.4 and 2.3 have a bug [see here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61671).
Just try to change your emulator to target version 4.2 or 4.3 and then change the orientation.

Happy Coding :)