# Activity takes incorrect alternative resources

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, android-orientation

I want to allow landscape and portrait on tablets, portrait only on phones.
[That question has already been asked,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627774/android-allow-portrait-and-landscape-for-tablets-but-force-portrait-on-phone) but I'm facing a bug with any of the proposed solutions.

I have various dimens [defined depending on the height of the device](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ScreenHeightQualifier) (h500dp, h400dp, etc.). So if I have my phone (411dp width, 731dp height on portrait) **rotated to landscape**, and I launch the app afterwards, even though **the activity appears on portrait**, it has taken the h400dp dimens; as if the height was evaluated depending on my current phone orientation (landscape). If I have the phone on portrait before launching the app, it takes the h500dp dimens, which would be the correct one.

The code I'm using is the one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627774/android-allow-portrait-and-landscape-for-tablets-but-force-portrait-on-phone/40637603#40637603); the relevant code is on the Activity `onCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (!isTablet()) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".login.LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: create a landscape layut

Comment: @nzala The real problem is that the app takes the resources as if it was in landscape. So if I define a landscape layout, it will take that, the same way it does it with h400dp dimens.

Comment: Can you share the manifest for this Activity

Comment: Please remove configChanges and try.

Comment: yes remove configChanges

Comment: add <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

See
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

If you want to provide a special layout for landscape, including while on large screens, then you need to use both the large and land qualifier:

```
MyProject/
    res/
        layout/              # default (portrait)
            main.xml
        layout-land/         # landscape
            main.xml
        layout-large/        # large (portrait)
            main.xml
        layout-large-land/   # large landscape
            main.xml
```

/

determine the type of device using screen dimensions. You could refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels)

On the second step you can change the screen orientation using `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`. There is another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654675/programmatically-lock-into-portrait-mode-for-certain-operations).

Answer (score 0):

Please remove configuration changes from `AndroidManifest.xml` of `Activity`

Setting `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`

will restrict the layout from being updated on `Orientation` change.